# Jquery Autocomplete only finding "C"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on a autocomplete in jquery that seems to only find the letter "C". And idea why this would happen? The other auto complete that I have using a json feed work okay but this one needs to display a grid of sort where you can choose from the first column of information (shape). When I type "C" I get the drop down but any combination beyond that does not work. Also if you just type in "L" or "A" it should pop up one of the selection but no such luck

JSON

```
[
    {
        "shape":"CLRE1 LAS",
        "eye":"50",
        "bridge":"18",
        "color":"all"
    },
    {
        "shape":"CLRE2 LAS",
        "eye":"48",
        "bridge":"18",
        "color":"all"
    },
    {
        "shape":"CLRK UOC",
        "eye":"54",
        "bridge":"18",
        "color":"all"
    },
    {
        "shape":"ABCD KCT",
        "eye":"105",
        "bridge":"25",
        "color":"all"
    }
]
```

Jquery Code

```
$.getJSON("resources/data/frameshape.json", function(projects) 
        {

        $( "#frameShaping" ).autocomplete({
            source: projects,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#frameShaping" ).val( ui.item.shape );
                return false;
            }
        })

        .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

            if (ul.children().length == 0){
                    ul.append( '<li class="t2"><p class="testing">Shape</p>
                    <p class="testing">Eye</p><p class="testing">Bridge</p>
                    <p class="testing">Color<p></li>' );
            }//end if

            return $( "<li></li>" )
                .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                .append( "<a><p class='linkage'>" 
                    + item.shape + "</p><p class='linkage'>" 
                    + item.eye + " </p><p class='linkage'>" 
                    + item.bridge + "</p><p class='linkage'> " + 
                    item.color +"</p></a>" )
                .appendTo( ul );

        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<input id="frameShaping" size="25"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete expects an array with objects containing a **`label`** property, a **`value`** property, or both. In order for this to work correctly, all you *should* have to do is add one of those properties to the objects in your array:

```
$.getJSON("resources/data/frameshape.json", function(projects) {
    $.each(projects, function (i, project) {
        project.label = project.shape;
    });

    $("#frameShaping").autocomplete({
        source: projects,
        /* other options */
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gUEjn/ (without the AJAX call, obviously).

---

Another option would be to supply your own filtering logic via the `source` option (this is especially useful if you do not want to add extra properties to your source objects). Basically, you can provide a function that accepts a request object and response callback and do whatever filtering you'd like inside of your function:

```
$("#frameShaping").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        /* this is also how jQueryUI builds a regex to find candidates internally */
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");

        response($.grep(projects, function (value) {
            return matcher.test(value.shape);
        }));
    },
    /* etc. */
})
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/P2WF9/

I would recommend the second option since it does not require you to iterate over your source array an extra time before initializing the widget.

As for why it was always working with an input of "C", it was actually working for any of the characters in the string: "`[object Object]`"

This is because [under the hood](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L551), jQueryUI is:

1. Building a regular expression from the input you've typed ("C" for example)
2. Using the [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method of the RegEx object (which accepts a string)

Now, when you pass anything to the `test` method, the argument will be converted into a string using `toString`, according to the ECMAScript specification for `RegExp.test`.

So in this particular case, when you take one of your objects and call `toString` on it, you get `[object Object]` which "C" matches. Since this is true for every object in your array, you actually get every item back if you search for any of those characters.

**Here's a boiled down example of what was happening:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZnA2w/